# Why does iterating over data result in massive memory usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, memory-management, rails-activerecord, delayed-job

I've got ten `users`, each with thousands (the counts are exactly 98956, 6954, 159732, 0, 40176, 541819, 218012, 52380, 93203, and 432) of `path` items. I need to iterate over each `user`, and work with their `paths`. I'm finding that each iteration increases memory usage, and after only a few users I'm using over a gigabyte of RAM.

I've simplified the code down to just gathering the `paths`, and the excessive memory usage is still occurring:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  points = user.paths.map { |path| [path.latitude, path.longitude, path.id] }
end
```

As somewhat of a side-note, I'm also experiencing this excessive memory usage with [delayed_job](http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job), where I have one job for each user. So, rather than gathering multiple users with `User.find_each do |user|`, it's just grabbing one user with `user = User.find(id)`. The memory usage grows from job to job, until eventually delayed_job exits (and I haven't been able to find any logging that corresponds with this - it simply goes away).

Is there anything that I can do to manage memory usage?

I'm using ruby-1.9.3-p484 and Rails 3.2.16

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use `find_each` wrong! Since you have too few users with a lot of paths, try to iterate a user's path with `find_each` so that not all paths of a user are loaded to memory.

```
User.find_each do |user|
  points = []
  user.paths.find_each { |path| points << [path.latitude, path.longitude, path.id] }
end
```

Comment: That makes sense, and uses considerably less RAM. I've been on a `map` rampage ever since reading [Anti-Pattern: Iteratively Building a Collection](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/iteration-as-an-anti-pattern). It looks like I need to be more careful about when I use it.